# How to join two tables with possibly the same value output?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm a beginner at programming and I would like to join the engineer table on the rma table. The engineer table shows the full name of the engineer and the engineer id corresponds to the rma engineer id. There are two types of engineers in the rma, eng_qc and eng_s, but they can be the same. How can I get both engineer names?

```
    JOIN eng ON
    CASE WHEN rma.eng_s = eng.eng_id THEN eng_qc WHERE rma.eng_s IN eng.eng_id END
    JOIN eng ON
    CASE WHEN rma.eng_qc = eng.eng_id THEN eng_s WHERE rma.eng_qc IN eng.eng_id END
    FROM rma
```

This is what I had but it doesn't work. Maybe someone has a solution?

**SOLVED**

I think I have not properly described the problem but I solved it by using multiple queries.

```
$rs = $db->query('SELECT * FROM `rma` ORDER BY `rma_id` ASC');

$rs1a = $db->query('SELECT * FROM `eng` WHERE `eng_id` = '.$r['eng_s'].'');
$r1a = $rs1a->fetch();
$rs1b = $db->query('SELECT * FROM `eng` WHERE `eng_id` = '.$r['eng_qc'].'');
$r1b = $rs1b->fetch();
```

Comment: You need to paste sample data that is your source and result data you need to get from source. Then someone can help. Because "doesn't work" means anything from "it shows error" to "my laptop exploded and burnt my office"

Comment: Are you talking about column aliases? `select engs.eng_id as eng_id_s, engqc.eng_id as eng_id_qc from rma inner join eng engs on engs.eng_id = rma.eng_s inner join eng engqc on engqc.eng_id = rma.eng_qc` (assumes both ids are used)

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Several people supplied answer that ought to have worked better than the solution you posted. I'd encourage you to take a closer look.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to get 2 names then can try to use this query:

```
   SELECT rma.eng_s,eng1.Name as name_s,rma.eng_qc, eng2.Name as name_qc 
   FROM rma JOIN eng eng1 ON rma.eng_s=eng1.eng_id 
            JOIN eng eng2 ON rma.eng_qc=eng2.eng_id
```

Comment: This gives the same problem as @marreBUS, when the engineers aren't the same I can't execute them both because they use the same column name while executing. I would like to store the id's in new names/output values in the query, but I don't now this is possible?

Comment: I have changed query...But it's will better if your give example what you want to get

Answer (score 0):

Could be done with a union all. However, if one engineer can have both IDs, the engineer's name will show twice.

```
SELECT 
rma.*,
e1.name
FROM rma 
JOIN eng e1 on rma.eng_s = e1.eng_id
UNION ALL
SELECT 
rma.*,
e2.name
FROM rma 
JOIN eng e2 on rma.eng_qc = e2.eng_id
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I would like the full name of both id's and those are stored in the engineer table. With your code I can select what I want but not execute. I can only execute the full name of one engineer name because they use the same column in the engineer table when execute them. I think the problem is that I have to give both id's a new name/output value in the query, but I don't know if that is possible?

Comment: You can change the name on a column by writing ".. as new_name". In the example above, you could write: e1.name as engineer_name. I am not sure that would help you in this case though, but a good thing to know when using UNION ALL is that it's preferred to ensure the names are similar in both tables that are joined.

Answer (score 0):

If you want both names, use two `left join`s:

```
select rma.*,
       eng_s.name as s_name,
       eng_qc.name as qc_name
from rma left join
     eng eng_s
     on rma.eng_s = eng_s.eng_id left join
     eng eng_qc
     on rma.eng_qc = eng_qc.eng_id
```